# Cannot find symbol: variable raw, location: class R

Tags: java, android

I did these steps and cannot solve the problem;

1. Build then Clean >> didn't solve
2. Removing Build folder from app level >> didn't solve
3. Removing Build folder from Project level >> didn't solve
4. Synch project with Gradle >> didn't solve

The code;

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sun);
        myPlayer.setLooping(false); //Set looping
    }
```

Error;

> error: cannot find symbol myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sun);

> symbol:   variable raw   location: class R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the import for `R`?

Example: `import <projectname>.R; import com.example_project.R;`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement a code from a tutorial. I tried all of the answers from the internet but cannot solved. The tutorial did not tell about adding any folder or sound. Then I realized I have to create a folder under "res" and add a sound from [Sound resources - Material Design](https://material.io/design/sound/sound-resources.html#) there is ton of alert sounds. This solved the problem.